# Error processing action bigquery.publish(0): BigQuery error: Dataset is not shared as editable

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working on new iOT project. I have a telit device that comunicates with m2m cloud plataform. I created a new project on google cloud and abilities the bigquery api. I created a new dataset but I did not create a table because I understand that this will be created when the first data will sent. I created a trigger on m2m cloud to send data when an condition is true. I have shared the dataset using the email generated by google cloud to the my application. I don't know if and where I should to put this email address on m2m cloud.

This is dataset share permissions.

[image]

Can you help me?

Rodrigo Rocha

Comment: Make sure when you share the dataset and choose the Can Edit option.

Comment: Pentium10, I did this. Look the print screen above.

Comment: hello Pentium10, do you have some idea about what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make sure that the email you share the dataset with is set to Can Edit so you can write tables.

Once that is done, to accomplish what you want to do, you'll have to run "append" jobs with a "CREATE IF NEEDED" disposition and a "WRITE_EMPTY" disposition. For more info, check out this link:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs

Comment: I didn't find this options when trying create jobs. Can you help me to find this?

Comment: Vaqar I seen this demo and for this it is not necessary create job.

Comment: Hi, Can anyone help me with this problem? I still can not solve this problem.